# renaming the name of the APP alone in Android Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, eclipse, rename

I created a wonderful app, but I want to rename the "application name" alone... (i.e the name seen by the user on the app icon ) .. ( this isn't package renaming)

How do I do it, without creating a new one ...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In the strings.xml file, there is an element `app_name` which is used in the AndroidManifest's application element as the app's name. **Just change the value of `app_name` in the strings.xml file to change the name of your app.**

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to refactor to change the name that people see. That is set in your res->values->Strings.xml file. You can call it what you want.

Answer (score 4):

you can try Refactor -> rename.