# How to edit AndroidManifest.xml file?

Tags: android, xml

How to open an AndroidManifest.xml file ? Which software must I use ? I want to change name of  android app

Comment: How you are creating project with eclipse or any other ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [renaming the name of the APP alone in Android Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373861/renaming-the-name-of-the-app-alone-in-android-eclipse-ide)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the name of your app, then the manifest file isn't the place to look for. Your app name can be changed from `strings.xml` file in the `res/values/` folder. You can do any formatting from within Eclipse itself during the development of your project/app.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bottom of the Eclipse Editor Screen , you will see tabs, from that Tab, select last one "AndroidManiFest.xml" It will display Xml in Text Format

Please look at this photo.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Click on the tab shown below in Eclipse]